# Have Picasso load image before row is viewable

Tags: android, android-listview, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images into a ListView cell and currently use a placeholder image.  So, as the user scrolls down, the placeholder image in the ImageView is replaced with the true image that needs to be there (from a URL).  However, that process of loading the true image/replacing the placeholder image does not happen until the cell is in view of the screen which means the user is constantly seeing the placeholder images change to the true images.  Is there a way to have that process done offscreen so that user does not see that and achieve a better user experience?

Comment: You need to find a way to have more views in listview than visible

Comment: And how would you go about doing that? As far as I know, a ListView does not have the same capabilities as a ViewPager where you can actually define how many offline views you can have for left/right swiping.

Comment: I think the title of this question is a bit inaccurate. My answer below addresses how to "Have Picasso load image before row is visible", but it seems what you really want to know is "How to prepare list item view before it's visible". I don't know if it's possible for ListView. You may probably want to use RecyclerView instead, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: It will allow you to specify how many invisible items you want to have by LayoutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#getExtraLayoutSpace(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)

Comment: Two things, I would agree with your statement that it is not a Picasso issue but a RecyclerView/LayoutManager issue.  In that regards, I am using the RecyclerView but I don't see any method on the LinearLayoutManager that would allow me to set the number of invisible items like I can with a ViewPager.

Comment: I looked at RecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize but as I understand it, that caches already viewed rows.  I paddled through http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2npsmb/any_way_to_precache_views_in_a_recyclerview and that person seems to have had the same issue as me, however, I don't have the same issue as him: "I had a blank white image in the view for testing purposes, and it was taking a second to override it, even though the images were cached."  I do have a preloaded image (through Picasso) and maybe that is the issue, the half-second to swap the preloaded image to the regular image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fetch()](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch--) method to warm up cache

```
Picasso.with(context).load(urlToPrefetch).fetch();
```

Note this serves as best-effort basis. Cache may be removed before you really need this depending on your configuration, and even if disk cache exists, Picasso will display placeholder until it process image (though it must be completed faster than when loading image with remote server).

Comment: Do you have an example of this.  I am currently loading it using something like this:  Picasso.with(parentFragment.getActivity())
                .load(category.getCategoryIconUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_icon)
                .into(viewHolder.categoryIcon);

Comment: But your example does not a) specify a placeholder image or b) the imageview that the fetched image is loaded into.

Comment: Yup, so this is the answer to "Have Picasso load image before row is viewable". 

You can call fetch() method upfront (e.g., even before user display listview). Images are load into cache, and then in your adapter's onGetView method, you will call same 
Picasso.with(parentFragment.getActivity()) .load(category.getCategoryIconUrl()) .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_icon) .into(viewHolder.categoryIcon);
Then underling HTTP client doesn't have to make network request but just read from cache, so you'll get shorter time during which placeholder is displayed